# ASP.NET MVC 4 Controller - CRUD for multiple models

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, model, controller, routes

I have a problem understanding if the following feature can be implemented as i have it in mind.

I need to have an admin panel on my e-commerce website, which should have CRUD operations for different parts of the data (customers, banned customers, orders, products etc).

I created a controller named 'AdminController'. Is it possible to have an implementation for this controller in order to create the following route configuration?

```
/{controller}/{model}/{action}/{id}
```

If there isn't any direct solution for this, could anyone please suggest a good way of implementing the admin panel?

Best regards,
Marius.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Marius you can create an area for admin panel.

Comment: What do you mean by creating an area?

Comment: Oh...now after a little bit of research, i understand what you mean. I am new to ASP.NET. Thanks. This will do it for me.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it.Its helpful to me.First Create a Area named Admin.Under Admin area craete your 'AdminController' in Controller folder.And then create a Custom routing.

```
routes.MapRoute(
                "Route",
                "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
                new { controller = "Admin", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
                 new[]{"ProjectName.Areas.Admin.Controllers.AdminController"}
            );
```

I think it's working for you.If not then then just change something as like `"Areas/Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}" or "/Admin/{controller}/{action}/{id}" or "/{controller}/{action}/{id}"`.